# How to programmatically create separate permutations of the same function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm attempting to create `onclick` events for a list of items that will basically achieve the same affect from a different sources of information that depends on the list item selected.

```
function buttonOnclick(whichButton) {
    document.getElementById("dialog0").innerHTML = document.getElementById("dialog" + whichButton.toString());
}

document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function breakerOnclick1() {
    buttonOnclick(1);
}

document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function breakerOnclick2() {
    buttonOnclick(2);
}

document.getElementById("button3").onclick = function breakerOnclick3() {
    buttonOnclick(3);
}

document.getElementById("button4").onclick = function breakerOnclick4() {
    buttonOnclick(4);
}

document.getElementById("button5").onclick = function breakerOnclick5() {
    buttonOnclick(5);
}
```

I would like to achieve this affect with a for loop instead of so manually. I know there is probably a more object oriented oriented or simple approach I'm missing being green to JavaScript.

How can this affect be achieved more programmatically?

**Solution:** Just to be clear on the answer to this question. The following produces the correct results quickly and reliably. All though, I'm sure there are other relevant suggestions below.

```
for (var i = 1; i < NUM_ENTRIES; i++){
    document.getElementById("button" + i).onclick = function(){
        var replacement = document.getElementById("dialog" + this.id[this.id.length-1]).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("dialog0").innerHTML = replacement;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you need the name of the function eg `breakerOnclick1`?

Comment: can't you set it from dom? if the dom is generated you can generate the onclick attribute to all buttonOnClick(buttonId) as well.

Comment: I don't think the title makes sense. I think you simply want to loop 5 times, and attach your event to `"button"+i`

Comment: If you use jQuery you can write this in about 3 lines of code.

Comment: yo, look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/1ej5mw4f/1/ (works, I'm not sure if I would use it tho)

Comment: @NinaScholz I just have a tendency to name any functions to produce legible (to me) source, of course it is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, assigning a DOM element to another element's innerHTML is just going to produce "[object HTMLDivElement]" or similar depending on the element. Perhaps you want

```
function buttonOnclick(whichButton) {
 document.getElementById("dialog0").innerHTML = document.getElementById("dialog" + whichButton.toString()).outerHTML;
 //which would make the innerHTML be `<div>stuff</div>`
}
```

As for your other issue, just use a query, iterate to assign, and pass the button's id number along

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=button]");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
 buttons[i].onclick = function(){
  buttonOnclick(this.id[this.id.length-1]);
 };
}
```

Comment: The first issue mentioned was definitely a typo on my part, I had meant to draw on the second element with the .innerHTML attribute instead of asking for the element itself.

Comment: .innerHTML only ever has produced the contents of the HTML from my observation. It seems as though you are suggesting there are cases ware this becomes a bad assumption?

Answer (score 0):

With a for loop?

```js
function buttonOnclick(whichButton) {
    document.getElementById("dialog0").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("dialog" + whichButton).innerHTML;
}
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    document.getElementById("button" + i).onclick = function (n) {
        return function () {
            buttonOnclick(n);
        }
    }(i);
}
```

```html
Selected: <strong><span id="dialog0"></span></strong><br>
<button id="button1">1</button> <span id="dialog1">abc</span><br>
<button id="button2">2</button> <span id="dialog2">def</span><br>
<button id="button3">3</button> <span id="dialog3">ghi</span><br>
<button id="button4">4</button> <span id="dialog4">jkl</span><br>
<button id="button5">5</button> <span id="dialog5">mno</span>
```

Comment: This is wrong, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue

Comment: You need parentheses around the function to make it an IIFE.

Comment: no, because it is an assignment, so the expression is evaluated

Comment: @Barmar The function's place as the RHS to an `=` operator already makes it an expression, I believe. Granted, I would always use parens for clarity, but I think this code is now syntactically valid and operates as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you want you're looking for.

```
function doSomething(id) {
    document.getElementById("dialog0").innerHTML = id;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById('button' + i).onclick = function(){
        doSomething(i);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you copying the innerHTML of the button to `dialog0`? That's not what his code does.

Comment: Fixed it to produce the same result.

Comment: Now it will put `buttonN` instead of `dialogN` into dialog0.

Comment: " i " is not persistent in this way as far as I have tested. I get a "cannot find null element" error

Answer (score 0):

to beginn you don't need to name your [Anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)

then you could use a simple for loop?

```
for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){
  document.getElementById("button"+i).onclick = (function(i) {
     return function(){
       buttonOnclick(i);
     })(i); //saving i for later
}
```

the best solution would be to do something like this

```
<button data-id="1" class="bar">
<button data-id="2" class="bar">
                 ....
```

and add a event listener to getElementsByClassName("bar"), and read the data-id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the button number in the function, get it from the element.

```
for var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    document.getElementById("button" + i).addEventListener("click", function () {
        var buttonNum = this.id.replace('button', '');
        buttonOnClick(buttonNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? You have the index inside of your loop, doing string interpolation is slower.

Comment: Are you really worried about the performance of something that runs once when you click? It's not a bottleneck.

Comment: Always. Although it's performance hit is arguably negligible in this case, it's also more fragile and prone to errors when this application scales.

Comment: On the other hand, this is more adaptable to changes where the parameter to the other function isn't just an index.

Answer (score 0):

A simple call to `forEach` can be used to iterate through the buttons.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('dialog-button'), function (el) {
  el.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("dialog0").innerHTML = document.getElementById(el.id.replace('button', 'dialog')).innerHTML;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialog0"></div>
<div id="dialog1">1</div>
<div id="dialog2">2</div>
<div id="dialog3">3</div>
<div id="dialog4">4</div>
<div id="dialog5">5</div>

<br />

<button id="button1" class="dialog-button">1</button>
<button id="button2" class="dialog-button">2</button>
<button id="button3" class="dialog-button">3</button>
<button id="button4" class="dialog-button">4</button>
<button id="button5" class="dialog-button">5</button>
```